# Is it possible to setup a Web Application running PHP inside an ASP.net 4.0 site using IIS 7.0?

Tags: php, asp.net, web-applications, iis-7

Is it possible to setup a Web Application running PHP inside an ASP.net 4.0 site using IIS 7.0.

I would like to setup a WordPress blog as a sub folder (Web Application) of a website but when I do this and navigate to the blog subfolder I get a vanilla http 403 error. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can install the PHP module for IIS.  It's pretty straightforward and allows IIS to work with PHP files. http://php.iis.net/

Comment: I am not having issues getting PHP to work on IIS 7. But I am having an issues getting PHP to work in a Web Application under a ASP.net site.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple way to install wordpress on iis http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/280/install-wordpress-on-iis/
regarding of installing it as a web application I don't think it is possible because it must have it's own application pool

Comment: Is it not possible to assign a different application pool to a Web Application than its parent web site?